# Derivative of $Ad:SU(2)\rightarrow \text{Aut}(\text{Lie}(SU(2))$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

In full generality $\text{ad}$ is the derivative of $\text{Ad}$.I would like to see this explicitly.

We want to calculate $d_e\text{Ad}:T_eSU(2)\rightarrow T_{Ad(e)}O(3)$. If we want to calculate this we need to do it at some $X\in T_eSU(2)$.

To calculate $d_e\text{Ad}(Y)$, we need a curve $\gamma(t)$ in $SU(2)$ with $\gamma(0)=e$ and $\gamma'(t)=Y$. I think $\gamma(t)=e^{tY}$ works. Then $d_e\text{Ad}(Y)=
\frac{d}{dt}Ad(e^{tY})$. But them I am stuck $Ad(g)$ is a homomorphism, i don't see how to take its derivative.

Comment: Try applying the homomorphism to something, and differentiate the result.

Comment: This confuses me. Why should the derivative of $\text{Ad}$ be related to the derivative of $\text{Ad}(g)$?

Comment: To flesh out @Zippy's hint,
$\frac{d}{dt}\text{Ad}(e^{tY}) X =\frac{d}{dt} (e^{tY}  X  e^{-tY}) =\text{Ad}(e^{tY}) ~[Y,X]\equiv \text{Ad}(e^{tY}) ~\text{ad}(Y) ~X$.